# Install LLVM in MacOS

Tags: c++, macos, llvm

I am learning LLVMand C++, but I find it hard to import LLVM into my project.

The first problem is my system has already installed clang and clang++ in `usr/bin`, but the other LLVM which was installed by brew is in `/opt/homebrew/opt/llvm`, is ok to delete clang in `usr/bin` and add `opt/homebrew/opt/llvm/bin` to env variable?

The second problem is how to link LLVM to my VSCode project, I try link LLVM by

```cpp
#include "/opt/homebrew/opt/llvm/include/llvm/IR/Constants.h"
```

but it can't work.

Thanks for any help !!!

Comment: Why bother with a homebrewed installation of LLVM when Xcode already provides that compiler?  Why not just use the Xcode installation, at least until you have learned enough to sort out this type of problem?

Answer (score 2):

- **Never delete system utilities**. Of any kind. For any reason.
- Read the information presented to you in `brew info llvm`. This information was shown to you when you installed it.
- Don't `#include` absolute paths.
- Learn how to use compiler/linker flags to tell your compiler where to find headers/libraries.
- Read the [libc++ documentation](https://libcxx.llvm.org/UsingLibcxx.html) to learn how to specify a specific libc++.
- Finally, use a tool like cmake to automate this for you.

  - A homespun makefile might be sufficient.

What you are attempting to do is highly non-trivial. As one of the comments suggests, I would also recommend getting familiar with what's baked in before you try switching to a custom version.